# How to import RESTService from my core application to JBPMSuite

Tags: java, jbpm, datamapper

Here I am trying to import REST Services into JBPM which I had already built in my core application. I looked into many blogs but all are explaining "how to build rest services in Jbpm". But I want to import the REST services which I already had.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the service task REST, and set its Assignments to consume your service, take a look at this link, in the "Rest Task Configuration" part
 https://karinavarela.me/2019/06/07/jbpm7-quicktips-service-tasks/

Hope this can help you.